# Maven skipping unit tests to skip finding dependancies

Tags: unit-testing, maven

Currently I have a build that have tests which have dependencies. What I wish to do is the run my build which would skip tests and trying to download the test dependencies since the dependencies are not in my maven repository. I have tried -Dmaven.test.skip=true in which it would skip the test but still try to download the dependency.

The dependency in the pom is

```
     <dependency>
      <artifactid>somthing</artifactid>
      <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
```

My question is if it possible to do this without editing the pom file and only through the mvn command.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985442/skipping-maven-test-dependency?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

For the command you used the explanation is:

Add the parameter

```
-Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

or

```
-DskipTests=true
```

in the command line, depending on whether you want to skip test compilation and execution or only execution.

For you need you could try this one...

[Exclude maven dependency for tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053316/exclude-maven-dependency-for-tests)